# Nativescript 6 HtmlView font color not applied

Tags: nativescript

I have a NS Core app with Nativescript 6.2.1.  I am testing on a physical ios device (iPhone 6 with OS 13).

On one of the screens I have an HtmlView set as:

```html
<HtmlView id="h-notices" html="{{ notices }}" tap="viewNotices" marginTop="15" backgroundColor="#f2f2f2" />
```

The notices variable is set on load as:

```js
model.set(
    "notices",
    '<span><font color="#a8b4b9">By clicking \'Continue\', you are agreeing to our </font><font color="#3ABA90">Terms of Use.</font></span>'
  );
```

The text loads fine, but in the default black color.  It looks like the font color attribute is not applied.  The same code works fine on Android.

Here is a Playground of the issue:  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=wZk6D3&v=9

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried both CSS and font tag, both work on my end in iOS and Android.

Comment: I see the colors on older (non os 13.x) phones, but on 13 I see black test on 2 different iPhones (6plus and X)  This is really strange

Comment: As an alternative, I ended up using FormattedString.  I still hope that someone will shed some light on the question above.

Comment: Can you confirm the exact version of iOS on your device.

Comment: One of the devices has 13.1.2 the other 13.2.1

Comment: I can confirm that this problem still unsolved with iOS 13+. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I think this is this issue reported on the NativeScript Github: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8368